# Youtube iFrame API in ES6 / modules

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to load a YT video via the api. This official tutorial snippet works basically out of the box when I output it directly onto a page. It's a different story when I try and incorporate it into my JS workflow with modules / webpack.

**Questions**:

How do I make these methods (play / mute / setLoop / stop / etc) available globally?

How do I create the script tag first and then run the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function?

Thanks all. Hope this isn't a completely useless question!

```
<script>
              // 1. Load up the script tag
              var tag = document.createElement('script');
              tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
              var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
              firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

              // 2. Creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
              var player;
              function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('a-spot-video-background', {
                    width: '1280',
                    height: '720',
                    videoId: 'T8v-gQeQZJY',
                    playerVars: {
                        autoplay: 1,
                        controls: 0,
                        modestbranding: 1,
                        rel: 0,
                        showinfo: 0,
                        loop: 1,
                        disablekb: 1,
                        color: 'white'
                    },
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
              }

              // 3. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
              function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.mute();
                event.target.playVideo();
                event.target.setLoop();
              }

              // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes. The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
              // the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
              var done = false;
              function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                    //setTimeout(stopVideo, 10000);
                    player.playVideo();
                    done = true;
                  }
              }
              function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
              }
          </script>
```

Comment: There are a lot of question at one place. Making `player` globally is your choice, now you define it using var. Either not use var, or use something like `window.player = new YT.Player`. Then you can use it via `window.player.playVideo()`. I don't get the second part though :)

Answer (score 0):

First question is answered in comment. This answers to second one:

```js
function loadScript(scriptUrl, globalName) {
  if (globalName && window[globalName]) 
    return Promise.resolve();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.type = "text/javascript";
    scr.src = scriptUrl;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
    scr.onload = (() => {
      !globalName || window[globalName] ? 
        resolve() : reject(Error('window.' + globalName + ' undefined'));
    });
    scr.onerror = () => reject(Error('Error loading ' + globalName||scriptUrl));
  });
}

var url = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
loadScript(url, "$")
  .then(() => console.log('jQuery loaded. Now I can call any jQuery method.'));
```

or you can use just `script.onload` event listener without promise. I like promise version because it gives you some additional options and has clear flow (without nesting or referencing across whole file).

Comment: The onload event is *not* good enough for the Youtube iframe api.  The script does some sort of asynchronous initialization, and then calls a global function when done.  You need to wait for that, or YT.Player will not be a class.

Comment: @dspeyer I don´t think so. We use [this lib](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube/blob/master/src/Youtube.js#L788) for years.